# How to set multiple request headers on each request

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm not sure how to set multiple request headers for each ajax request. This is what I have now:

```
Ext.Ajax.on("beforerequest", function(conn, request){     
    request.headers = request.headers || {};     
    return request.headers.Authorization = "Bearer " + Ext.util.Cookies.get("token"); 
}, this);
```

As you can see, I'm setting here just one Authorization token. But now I want to set one more header in order to submit so called "refresh" token to the server. How can I do that? By the way, I need to access cookies and set headers on each request, because data in this cookies may change. So I can not set headers once and for all time.

Comment: Why can't you assign a second header to `request.headers`? And I'm fairly sure you don't need to *return* a header value from the function, not least because it'll just be the value.

Comment: yeah, drop the return, and just do multiple request.headers["header-name"] = "some value";

Comment: Thank you, guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add multiple headers to the `headers` object. Also note you don't need (or want) to return the value of any of those headers from the function:

```
Ext.Ajax.on("beforerequest", function(conn, request){     
    request.headers = request.headers || {};     
    request.headers.Authorization = "Bearer " + Ext.util.Cookies.get("token");
    request.headers.SomthingElse = Ext.util.Cookies.get("something-else"); // ***
}, this);
```